# Text hidden with UITextView Resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. I'm running into some difficulty in resizing the textview (I'm not using autolayout). It's working almost perfectly, accept that when the textview resizes, the text scrolls up on the first line break. It then corrects itself whenever I type the next character. The problem is illustrated here:

[image]

[image]

The code I'm using to resize the textview and update the cell is here:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    textView.frame = newFrame;
    NSLog(@"text: %f",textView.frame.size.height);

    [self.tableview beginUpdates];
    [self.tableview endUpdates];
}
```

The output from the NSLog is 62.5 and 62.5 for both the first s and the second s.

Comment: try to set content inset of UITextView from top

Comment: Why don't you add autolayout constrains to this?